# UNIX time to DateList

Tags: date-and-time

I have data that is timestamped with UNIX time, which is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 UTC. Unfortunately, it seems that most of the date and time functions in Mathematica are based on the system's local time zone. How can I convert a UNIX timestamp to a `DateList` in UTC?

Comment: DateList[] takes an absolute time as input. But M absolute time start in 1900 and not 1970. Hence take your Unix time, and add to it `AbsoluteTime[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}]`, which is `2208988800` seconds. Now your Unix list become M absolute time, then you can use `DateList` on it. Will this work for you? If you show some input will help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since *Mathematica* version 10.1 there is the function [`FromUnixTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromUnixTime.html) that performs the conversion from a UNIX timestamp to a `DateObject`.

```
FromUnixTime[1427793986]
```

[image]

```
FromUnixTime[1427793986] // DateList
```

> `{2015, 3, 31, 11, 26, 26.}`

```
FromUnixTime[0, TimeZone -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: The [associated Wolfram Blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/07/09/new-in-the-wolfram-language-iso-dates-and-more/) has additional background on this and other new date & time abilities (like ISO 8601 support).

Answer (score 6):

The number of seconds between January 1, 1900 and January 1, 1970 can be given by `AbsoluteTime[{1970, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0}]`. There is also `DateList` which, if given a number, will calculate what the date would be if that was the number of seconds given by `AbsoluteTime`.

```
DateList[AbsoluteTime[], TimeZone -> 2]
```

> {2013, 8, 26, 2, 28, 7.97767}

```
DateList[AbsoluteTime[{1970, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0}] + First@ReadList["!date +%s"]]
```

> {2013, 8, 26, 2, 28, 7.}

The slight difference seems to be because the UNIX timestamp rounds downwards.

(`First@ReadList["!date +%s"]` only gives the current timestamp on UNIX systems. Everyone else will have to paste in their own timestamps to try it out. Also, I'm using my own time zone which is +2.)

Comment: Generalizing, the offset is `AbsoluteTime[{1970, 1, 1, TimeZone[], 0, 0}]`? I'm super confused! I asked about this as a new question here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77974/converting-between-absolutetime-and-unix-time

Comment: @dreeves Yes, or `$TimeZone` (`TimeZone[]` appears to be undocumented.)