# Converting between AbsoluteTime and Unix time

Tags: conversion, date-and-time, unix

By trial and error, I've found that the following gives the current Unix time:

```
AbsoluteTime[] - UPOCH
```

where UPOCH can be defined in any of the following ways:

```
UPOCH = Round[AbsoluteTime[{1970,  1,  1,  0,         0, 0}, TimeZone->-14]]
UPOCH = Round[AbsoluteTime[{1969, 12, 31, 10,         0, 0}, TimeZone->0]]
UPOCH = Round[AbsoluteTime[{1970,  1,  1, TimeZone[], 0, 0}]]
UPOCH = 2208963600
```

Just as you can subtract UPOCH to convert Mathematica's AbsoluteTime to Unix time, you can convert a Unix time to Mathematica's epoch time by adding UPOCH.

My question is why? Why isn't it `AbsoluteTime[{1970,1,1, 0,0,0}, TimeZone->0]`?

Related question: [UNIX time to DateList](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31106/unix-time-to-datelist)

UPDATE: Here's what you actually want (thanks to @2012rcampion):

```
UPOCH = AbsoluteTime[DateObject[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, TimeZone->0]]
```

Comment: dreeves, I haven't seen you post in a long time!  Welcome to the new site.  I hope you'll stick around. :-)

Comment: Thank you! I take it the cool kids are all here now, as opposed to using the mathematica tag on StackOverflow? Or is the latter still the right place for sufficiently programmy questions?

Comment: There are exceptions, e.g. High Performance Mark, but just about everyone with skill is over here now.  The subject scope is quite broad; for the most part if it is *Mathematica* related it is accepted.  Some questions that mention *Mathematica* but otherwise have little to do with it may be migrated to [Math.SE], [Stats.SE], or [DSP.SE].

Comment: Your 4 examples for calculating `UPOCH` give different results: `2208934800`, `2208934800`, `2208992400` and `2208963600`. Is this correct?

Comment: Oh, interesting, they all give 2208963600 in Mathematica 10 for me. So this is a new mystery! With an explicit TimeZone given I'd have thought that AbsoluteTime would give consistent results on different systems.

Comment: [I am curious: is the official MathematicaScript based on your MASH?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107436/wolframscript-unix-script-parameters-on-raspberry-pi#comment290504_107436)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}` is shorthand for a `DateObject`, namely this one:

```
DateObject[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}]
```

This represents January 1, 1970 *in your current time zone*.  The origin of UNIX time is January 1, 1970 *UTC*:

```
DateObject[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, TimeZone -> 0]
```

Note now that the returned `DateObject` displays with the time zone GMT:

[image]

For example, in a computer set to EDT time (`$TimeZone === -4.`), that date object in canonical form is:

```
DateList@DateObject[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, TimeZone -> 0]
(* {1969, 12, 31, 20, 0, 0.} *)
AbsoluteTime@%
(* 2 208 974 400 *)
```

To compute UNIX time, we need to find the difference between the current time and the origin.  We can either take the difference of the respective `AbsoluteTime`s (with the computation done in our time zone):

```
AbsoluteTime[] - 
  AbsoluteTime[
   DateObject[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, TimeZone -> 0]] // Round
(* 1427139257 *)
```

We could also forgo `AbsoluteTime` and ask Mathematica more directly what the difference is:

```
DateDifference[DateObject[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, TimeZone -> 0], 
  DateObject[], "Second"] // Round
(* Quantity[1427139257, "Seconds"] *)
```

Note that this emits a `Quantity` object.  With Mathematica's built-in unit support, I find this more useful, although you can always strip out the value with `QuantityMagnitude`.

The times given by both of these methods agree with [Wolfram|Alpha's answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=unix+time).

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that Mathematica's `AbsoluteTime[]` returns the number of seconds since 1900-01-01_00:00:00 in *your system's time zone*. So you probably don't want to use `AbsoluteTime[]` the way you use epoch time in other languages, where you can count on it to be consistent and universal across systems. So the following seems to consistently give actual current Unix time:

```
Round[AbsoluteTime[TimeZone -> 0] - AbsoluteTime[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}]]
```

But I'm still confused; why isn't the second call to AbsoluteTime like so:

```
AbsoluteTime[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, TimeZone->0]
```

### Update: Here's what to actually do

In light of @Karsten's answer and taking the insight from @2012rcampion's answer, here's what I now recommend:

```
(* Mathematica 10.1 introduced UnixTime; this is a backport *)
If[Names["UnixTime"] == {},
  UPOCH = AbsoluteTime[DateObject[{1970,1,1, 0,0,0}, TimeZone->0]];
  UnixTime[x___] := Round[AbsoluteTime[x] - UPOCH];
  FromUnixTime[t_] := DateObject[AbsoluteTime[t+UPOCH]];
];
```

That will work for most things you'll want it for in old versions, I believe, and no need to even change your code when you upgrade. That chunk just becomes superfluous.

Comment: Because `{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}` still represents a time in your time zone.  Try this instead: `AbsoluteTime[TimeZone -> 0] - AbsoluteTime[DateObject[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, TimeZone -> 0], 
 TimeZone -> 0]`, or simply `AbsoluteTime[] - AbsoluteTime[DateObject[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, TimeZone -> 0]]`

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'll update this answer later to incorporate this unless you want to turn this into a separate answer.

Comment: oops, already done.... I need to refresh the comments more frequently it seems

Comment: Keep in mind that  `AbsoluteTime[]` ignores leap seconds. I think this fact is missing in the documentation.

Comment: @RolfMertig, is that different from what epoch times in other languages do?

Answer (score 3):

Since version 10.1 of *Mathematica* there are the functions [`UnixTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnixTime.html) and [`FromUnixTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromUnixTime.html) performing the conversion between Unix times and `DateObject`s.

Current Unix time:

```
UnixTime[]
```

> `1427795462`

UPOCH:

```
AbsoluteTime@FromUnixTime[0, TimeZone -> 0]
```

> `2208996000`