# WolframScript Unix - Script Parameters on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, command-line, unix

I'm currently trying to run a script with 2 parameters which gets called via a BASH script. The script runs fine however the list of passed parameters , `$ScriptCommandLine`, always stays empty.

According to the [wolfram website](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ScriptCommandLine.html) the list stays empty , *"If the Wolfram Language kernel was run in a way other than via a WolframScript mechanism, the $ScriptCommandLine gives an empty list."*

So the script has to use the interpreter  `#!/usr/local/bin/WolframScript -script`.
However the raspberry pi version of Wolfram/Mathematica does not have this executable! So i tried using the only executable i found, `#!/usr/bin/wolfram -script` which leads to the fact that `$ScriptCommandLine` stays empty.

Do i have to install something additional / Do i have to update something? Or is there any workaround (thought about writting the parameters in a textfile with bash and let the script import these )

Comment: The `MathematicaScript` executable is at the location `/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/10.3/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-ARM/MathematicaScript`.  But I cannot get it to work.  It tells me `error: The file /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/10.3/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux/WolframKernel is not found or is not executable.` It is looking for `WolframKernel` at the wrong location.  I don't know how to change that.

Comment: What's very interesting is that if I look into `MathematicaScript` (an executable binary), I find references to `mash.c`.  [That rings a bell!](http://ai.eecs.umich.edu/people/dreeves/mash/pre6/)

Answer (score 2):

The [wolframscript](http://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/) Wolfram Language script interpreter is now available on the Raspberry Pi and will set `$ScriptCommandLine` appropriately

```
pi@testpi3lx:~ $ wolframscript -code '{$Version, $ScriptCommandLine}'

{11.0.1 for Linux ARM (32-bit) (January 17, 2017), 
  {wolframscript, -code, {$Version, $ScriptCommandLine}}}
```

Comment: It's a pity though that a single run takes 12 seconds ... (overclocked RPi 1 B with 512 MB RAM)